# How to check if multiple files exist in different directories

Tags: python, io

I know how to use python to check to see if a file exists, but what I am after is trying to see if multiple files of the same name exist throughout my working directory. Take for instance:

```
gamedata/areas/ 
# i have 2 folders in this directory
# testarea and homeplace


1. gamedata/areas/testarea/
2. gamedata/areas/homeplace/
```

Each folder of homeplace and testarea for instance contains a file called 'example'

Is there a pythonic way to use 'os' or similiar to check to see if the file 'example' can be found in both testarea and homeplace?

Although is their a way to do this without manually and statically using

```
os.path.isfile()
```

because throughout the life of the program new directories will be made, and I don't want to constantly go back into the code to change it.

Comment: I believe you want to have a look to `os.walk` or (even better) to `os.path.walk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in every directory bellow `gamedata/areas/`:
This only goes down one level, you could extend it to go down as many levels as you want.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isdir, isfile, join
base_path = "gamedata/areas/"
files = listdir(base_path)
only_directories = [path for path in files if isdir(join(base_path,path))]

for directory_path in only_directories:
    dir_path = join(base_path, directory_path)
    for file_path in listdir(dir_path):
        full_file_path = join(base_path, dir_path, file_path)
        is_file = isfile(full_file_path)
        is_example = "example" in file_path
        if is_file and is_example:
            print "Found One!!"
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
places = ["testarea", "homeplace"]
if all(os.path.isfile(os.path.join("gamedata/areas/", x, "example") for x in places)):
    print("Missing example")
```

If the condition is false, this doesn't tell you *which* subdirectory does not contain the file `example`, though. You can update `places` as necessary.

Comment: perfect I will give that a shot, I don't care knowing where it exists as long as it just does.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, `os.walk` is your friend:

```
import os

ROOT="gamedata/areas"
in_dirs = [path for (path, dirs, filenames)
                 in os.walk(ROOT)
                 if 'example' in filenames]
```

`in_dirs` will be a list of subdirectories where `example` is found

Comment: With arbitrary depth. Notice that `os.walk` won't follow symlinks if you don't tell it too (read the doc about it)